# MapView not supporting layout_height=wrap_content

Tags: android-layout

I'm building a layout that contains two buttons and a MapView.  The buttons should be placed above and below the MapView.  I've tried several combinations of layouts (Relative, Linear, Frame...), but the MapView does not support the layout_height=wrap_content unless I use a specific height like layout_height="200dp".

The tope button is displayed, but the bottom button is not.  Below is my test XML file.

Any suggestions?

android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

```
<Button     
    android:id="@+id/btn1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"          
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button1" 
    android:background="#FF0000" />

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:apiKey="my map key (removed for example)"
/>           

<Button     
    android:id="@+id/btn2" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"          
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button2"
    android:background="#00FF00" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue (my mapview was between two layouts instead of buttons), and solved it with "height=0dp" and "weight=1" so the mapview adjusts to the above and below layouts.

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
  android:id="@+id/map1"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="0dp"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:apiKey="my map key (removed for example)"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm on a brand new machine and don't have anything to test this with, but this might work:

```
<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"          
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<Button     
    android:id="@+id/btn1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"          
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button1" 
    android:background="#FF0000" />

<Button     
    android:id="@+id/btn2" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"          
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button2"
    android:background="#00FF00" />      

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:apiKey="my map key (removed for example)"
    android:layout_below="@id/btn1"
    android:layout_above="@id/btn2"
/></RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, The Mapview still does not play well with other layouts, but this will do.